# How can one determine the most effective method for establishing a success metric for a quarterly objectives?

Tags: software-industry, management, career-development, software-development, leadership

My manager recently took on the additional role of Frontend Architect, and he's asked me to step up and assist with day-to-day responsibilities for the team. Currently, I hold the position of Intermediate Developer.

As our company shifts back to quarterly performance reviews, we've discussed specific outcomes he'd like to see me achieve this quarter. Here are the top three outcomes we've decided on:

1. Ensure the team follows through on their commitments and completes all assigned tasks.
2. Foster seamless integration and positive contributions from offshore contractors.
3. Target a reduction in bug counts to 10 or fewer.

Is there any framework that help me nail down the success criteria for these?

Comment: Do you mean how can you ensure you meet these? Or how can you measure if you've met them?

Comment: What kind of metrics did your manager use before ?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you are accepting all the responsibility but probably do not have any power or authority.  That would be a terrible position to be in with a guarantee of failure.

You need to negotiate for

- the authority to give tasks to the team
- the authority to assign and change responsibilities, priorities and resources
- the possibility for sequestering external resources to meet the goals.
- a message sent to the team by your manager advising them that you have this authority and responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

- Are the outcomes measurable? If not, you'll probably have a hard time arguing that you met them at the performance review.
- Are the outcomes achievable? Since the detailed goals are not yet fixed, it's hard to say in advance, and it will depend on the actual tasks being assigned and actual bugs being found.

1. "Ensure the team follows through on their commitments and completes all assigned tasks" depends on whether task assignments are reasonable and have reasonable completion dates. So your success here hinges on things you can't influence.
2. "Foster seamless integration and positive contributions from offshore contractors." - can you count and measure them somehow?
3. "Target a reduction in bug counts to 10 or fewer." - I suppose only reported and accepted bugs are counted, but you're still somehow at the mercy of events not under your control, such as the capacity of your team to analyze and fix bugs within a reasonable time. This may conflict with goal 1 when your team's capacity is filled so that there's not enough time to fix bugs.

I don't know which tools or approaches can help you to achieve the goals, but clear documentation about the expectations (as lists of tasks assigned, bugs reported, tasks delegated to offshore contractors) and results will help you track your performance and will help you to be well prepared for the reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Use a task tracking system. Estimate "function points" of tasks before starting them ("planning poker") and track how those map to hours to complete them. Determine what your team's normal cadence (rate of completion) is, in FP per unit time. Use that to predict how long it will take to complete additional tasks. Lather, rinse, repeat. This is pretty standard modern project planning.